# Cómo encontrar elementos de A que no estén en B?

Tags: r

Tengo un df1

```
ID Padre Madre
1 M0FR645331030147M0   FR645315380096 H0ES1500301571052010
2 M0FR645331050104M0   FR64529351013  000000000000000002010
3 M0FR645335610058M0   FR645075680098 00000000000000002011
4 M0FR64533650006000   00000000000000 00000000000000002010
5 M0FR645336540068M0   FR645073390099000 00000000000002014
6 M0FR64533932021300   0000000000000000000000000000002006
```

y un 2

```
  ID
1 FR640446050750
2 FR645222990075
3 FR645315760076
4 FR645072390147
5 FR645178660108
6 FR645036090080
```

Quiero generar una lista aparte de los elementos del ID del dataframe 1 que no están en el dataframe 2. Tengo un problema adicional y es el que el ID del df1 siempre empieza con dos caracteres adicionales que no están en df2, con lo cual quiero que sólo considere la comparación de elementos iguales del segundo caracter en adelante.

He intentado:

```
dataframe1[!(Dataframe1$ID %in% dataframe2$ID)]
```

pero es un comando incompleto...

¿Cómo debo hacerlo?

Comment: También termina con dos caracteres adicionales? puedes extraer los caracteres adicionales (p.e. con ´stringr::str_sub()´) creando una ID2 así funcionaria tu código!

Answer (score 2):

En el siguiente ejemplo agrego una fila adicional al `dataframe2` y extraje los caracteres iniciales y finales, así funciona tu código.

```
library(tibble)

dataframe1<-tribble(
  ~ID, ~Padre, ~Madre,
  "M0FR645331030147M0",   "FR645315380096", "H0ES1500301571052010", # Agrege este id al df2
  "M0FR645331050104M0",   "FR64529351013",  "000000000000000002010",
  "M0FR645335610058M0",   "FR645075680098", "00000000000000002011",
  "M0FR64533650006000",   "00000000000000", "00000000000000002010",
  "M0FR645336540068M0",   "FR645073390099000", "00000000000002014",
  "M0FR64533932021300",   "00000000000000000", "00000000000002006" 
)

dataframe2<-tribble(
  ~ID,
   "FR640446050750",
   "FR645222990075",
   "FR645315760076",
   "FR645072390147",
   "FR645178660108",
   "FR645036090080",
   "FR645331030147" #Agregue esta fila 
)

library(stringr)
# Extraer caracteres adicionales, guardar en nueva ID
dataframe1$ID2<-str_sub(dataframe1$ID,3,16)

#Excluir coincidencias 
dataframe1[!dataframe1$ID2%in%dataframe2$ID,]  

# A tibble: 5 x 4
                  ID             Padre                 Madre            ID2
               <chr>             <chr>                 <chr>          <chr>
1 M0FR645331050104M0     FR64529351013 000000000000000002010 FR645331050104
2 M0FR645335610058M0    FR645075680098  00000000000000002011 FR645335610058
3 M0FR64533650006000    00000000000000  00000000000000002010 FR645336500060
4 M0FR645336540068M0 FR645073390099000     00000000000002014 FR645336540068
5 M0FR64533932021300 00000000000000000     00000000000002006 FR645339320213
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rolando! Ahora todo funciona como necesitaba :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es recortar el `ID` usando [`substring()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substr.html) para quitar los dos primeros caracteres, pero me da la impresión que también habría que quitar los últimos.

```
# Buscamos los dataframe1.ID a los que recortamos desde el 3er caracter hasta el final
dataframe1[!substring(dataframe1$ID, 3) %in%  dataframe2$ID,]

# O bien buscamos los df1.ID recortando los 2 caracteres iniciales y los 2 finales
dataframe1[!substring(dataframe1$ID, 3, 3 + nchar(dataframe2$ID[1])-1) %in%  dataframe2$ID,]
```

En el primer caso `substring(dataframe1$ID, 3)`, recorta desde el caracter 3 y al no indicar un parámetro final será el resto de la cadena. El segundo caso, si es que efectivamente es como imagino, usamos el parámetro `stop` para indicar hasta dónde recortaremos:  `substring(dataframe1$ID, 3, 3 + nchar(dataframe2$ID[1])-1)` recorta desde el caracter 3 únicamente la longitud que tienen los `dataframe2$ID`.